# Erro memória servidor wildfly

Tags: java, spring, servidor

Tentei importar um arquivo de 66 megas, e deu este erro no **wildfly** : **Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

Além de incluir esta configuração no spring.

> @Bean public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
>     CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new
>   CommonsMultipartResolver();
>     multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(524288000);
>     multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(524288070);
>     multipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");  return
>   multipartResolver; }

Modifiquei no servidor o tamanho do arquivo, conforme imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entendei que o servidor está com pouca memória.

Fui no arquivo **standalone.conf**, do servidor e modifiquei de:

**JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"**

para:

**JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2056m -XX:MaxPermSize=2056m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"**

Mesmo assim continuo com o mesmo erro ?

O que pode ser ?

Imagem do servidor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja no menu superior em `Runtime`, e depois no menu ao lado na esquerda `JVM` adicione as informações de Heap aqui também (Used e Committed)

Comment: Obrigado @PauloH.Hartmann, adicionei na pergunta o que pediu.

Comment: Esta estranho, certeza que você utiliza as configurações do _standalone_ no servidor? (pode ser que seu servidor esteja pegando as configurações do _standalone-full_ por exemplo) Se eu não me engano a memória descrita no campo Committed Heap deveria ser o que esta descrito na configuração -Xms do arquivo .conf

Comment: Entendi mais ou menos. Aonde está este arquivo ?

Como faço para alterar ?

Comment: Como você esta iniciando o servidor WildFly? Você esta iniciando ele através de alguma IDE, tipo netbeans? ou esta indo no shell e subindo ele por lá?

Comment: Estou iniciando pelo eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Tente configurar no Eclipse, pois esse arquivo standalone.conf só é carregado quando se executa o wildfly pelo shell atravez do standalone.sh ou se estiver no windows standalone.bat

Comment: Considere colocar essa informação no comentário.